# Javascript natural sort objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object

I have an object array like

```
array[0] = {id: 1, name: "First"}
array[1] = {id: 2, name: "Second"}
```

Which I've tried to sort by `name` field by using:

```
Array.prototype.alphanumSort = function (caseInsensitive) {
for (var z = 0, t; t = ((typeof this[z] == "string" || typeof this[z] == "undefined") ? this[z] : this[z].name); z++) {
    this[z] = new Array();
    var x = 0, y = -1, n = 0, i, j;

    while (i = (j = t.charAt(x++)).charCodeAt(0)) {
        var m = (i == 46 || (i >= 48 && i <= 57));
        if (m !== n) {
            this[z][++y] = "";
            n = m;
        }
        this[z][y] += j;
    }
}

this.sort(function (a, b) {
    for (var x = 0, aa, bb; (aa = a[x]) && (bb = b[x]); x++) {
        if (caseInsensitive) {
            aa = aa.toLowerCase();
            bb = bb.toLowerCase();
        }
        if (aa !== bb) {
            var c = Number(aa), d = Number(bb);
            if (c == aa && d == bb) {
                return c - d;
            } else return (aa > bb) ? 1 : -1;
        }
    }
    return a.length - b.length;
});

for (var z = 0; z < this.length; z++)
    this[z] = this[z].join("");
}
```

but the list that I'm getting back from it contains an array with just the `name` field from it, without the corresponding `id`. Why is this happening?
Is there a way to apply this algorithm to filter objects?
I'm new in JavaScript, so please be gentle.

Comment: had you have a look to [`String#localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) and the options?

Comment: **please** dont put methods on the prototype chain

Comment: it's OK @AyushGupta - OP never actually USES that code anyway

Comment: @NinaScholz What if I have situations like 'Ex 10' and 'Ex 2'? The second one should be the first one

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [sorting with map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Sorting_with_map) and [`String#localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) with `options`

> **sensitivity**
>
> Which differences in the strings should lead to non-zero result values. Possible values are:
>
> - `"base"`: Only strings that differ in base letters compare as unequal. Examples: `a ≠ b`, `a = á`, `a = A`.
> - `"accent"`: Only strings that differ in base letters or accents and other diacritic marks compare as unequal. Examples: `a ≠ b`, `a ≠ á`, `a = A`.
> - `"case"`: Only strings that differ in base letters or case compare as unequal. Examples: `a ≠ b`, `a = á`, `a ≠ A`.
> - `"variant"`: Strings that differ in base letters, accents and other diacritic marks, or case compare as unequal. Other differences may also be taken into consideration. Examples: `a ≠ b`, `a ≠ á`, `a ≠ A`.
>
> The default is "variant" for usage "sort"; it's locale dependent for usage "search".
>
> **numeric**
>
> Whether numeric collation should be used, such that "1" < "2" < "10". Possible values are `true` and `false`; the default is `false`. This option can be set through an options property or through a Unicode extension key; if both are provided, the `options` property takes precedence. Implementations are not required to support this property.

```js
var array = ['Ex 10', 'Ex 2', 'a 10.1', 'a 1.1', 'a 10.0', 'a 2.0'];

array.sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b, undefined, { numeric: true, sensitivity: 'base' }));

console.log(array)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [String.prototype.localeCompare](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare)

```js
var arr = [
  {id: 1, name: "Third"},
  {id: 2, name: "Fifth"},
  {id: 3, name: "Second"},
  {id: 4, name: "Fourth"},
  {id: 5, name: "First"}
];

arr.sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name, undefined, { numeric: true, sensitivity: 'base' }));

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: In situations like sorting names like 'First 10' and 'First 2', the second one should be first

Comment: If there was no `name` property in some object, your code would compare other strings with string `"undefined"`

Comment: In that case i would suggest making a custom function to compare two strings which returns 1, -1, 0 to Array.sort() as suggested below by vizsatiz. I will try to do it and update my answer if i get some free time.

Comment: @PR7 there's no need for custom function, see [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52661352/7404943)

Comment: @Dana There is no need to write a custom compare function. You can use the options in localeCompare function. I have updated my answer. barbsan Thanks :)

Comment: @PR7 Why are you also using .sort inside function?

Comment: @Dana Sorry i was busy and forgot to update the code properly. I have corrected it now.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using Lodash (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js):

```
array[0] = {id: 1, name: "First"}
array[1] = {id: 2, name: "Second"}
array = _.orderBy(array, 'name', 'desc')
```